# Flask Security Is using id instead of email in where clause

Tags: python, flask-admin, flask-peewee

I am using flask security to login to my admin panel. It was using the email and password just fine, but recently the login is requiring the id instead of the email. As far as I know the default behavior is to use the email column. When investigating I found that the SQL query is trying to use the id in the where clause instead of the email. My models are set up correctly with peewee so I am confused as to what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

It was a peewee version problem. The newest version breaks flask-security.